# Setting otherlangs from the command line using pandoc

Tags: latex, pandoc

Using pandoc, I managed to produce the following output using the YAML prolog.

```
---
lang: fr
otherlangs: [en]
---
```

Generates this latex code.

```
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,english,main=french]{babel}
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{french}
  \setotherlanguage[]{english}
\fi
```

But, I cannot manage to have it working using the commande-line arguments. This what I tried.

```
$ pandoc -s -t latex -V lang=fr -V otherlangs="[en]"
```

Which produces:

```
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,main=french]{babel}
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{french}
\fi
```

Any hints on how I should pass de `otherlangs` variable from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible since the `-M` option (and probably `-V` as well) parse values

> as YAML boolean or string values

and `otherlangs` needs to be a list. What's your use case?

You shouldn't have to set `otherlangs` manually as it's extracted from spans and divs with the lang attribute (see the [MANUAL](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#language-variables)), for example:

```
my [english words]{lang=en} inside a span

::: {lang=en}
followed by a native div (using this syntax since pandoc 2.0)
with another paragraph
:::
```

If you absolutely must set this info from the command-line, using a custom LaTeX template that contains, say, the following (if you're using Polyglossia/XeLaTeX):

```
\setotherlanguage[]{$myOtherLangs$}
```

and calling it with `pandoc -V myOtherLangs="english,french"` should solve your use-case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll open an issue. My use case is exactly that, setting the `otherlangs` attribute from the command-line.

Comment: you can also modify the LaTeX template... or ask around on pandoc-discuss before opening an issue.

Comment: The less hacks are involved the better.